# Interferences between coherent sources facing each other

Tags: waves, interference, coherence

I don't understand how 2 coherent sources of longitudinal waves (i.e.: sound) facing each other have destructive interferences at certain fixed points between the 2 sources.

How come those points aren't moving with time since the waves are moving toward each others?

Sincerely,

Comment: It could be shown formally. You should just calculate formally two waves, for example the first wave is:
$$ E_1 = E \cdot cos(\omega t-kx) $$
and the second wave is:
$$ E_2 = E \cdot cos(\omega t+k(x+l)) $$
Then you superpose them and using the trigonometry formulas of the sum of cosinus (to get the multiplication of cos or sin) you should get maxima and minima

Comment: Perfect, it just came to my mind that it is the exact equivalent of changing the sign on $\omega t$ (as Farcher wrote) ratter than $kx$ since $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$.. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $E_1+E_2 =E\cos(kx−\omega t)+E\cos(kx+\omega t)=2E\cos(kx)\cdot \cos(\omega t)$ the result is a standing wave.

At a position $x$ a particle oscillates with a frequency $\omega$, which is the $\cos(\omega t)$ term with an amplitude $2E\cos(kx)$, which you will note varies from $2E$ at an antinode to $0$ at a node.

Comment: Can't vote yet. Thank you though, you made it clear to me.